# Node.js - Async.js map function only showing results of the first iteration?

Tags: node.js

I'm mapping an array when I finish the mapping I should  return the whole array, but in my code the first element that it return.

> In this function I'm using async.map to call getShippingMethods function, after getting the result I'm calling resolve function, but the problem the resolve function return just the first element of the array.

```
   function getShippingZones() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            pool.getConnection(function (error, connection) {
                if (error) reject("error in connection")
                else {
                    connection.query("select * from shipping_zone", function (error, result, fields) {
                        if (error) reject(error)
                        else {
                            async.map(result, getShippingMethods, function (res) {
                                resolve(res)
                            })
                        }
                    })
                }
            })
        })
    }





   function getShippingMethods(result, callback) {
    pool.getConnection(function (error, connection) {
        if (error) return (error)
        else {
            var id = result.id
            var name = result.zone_name
            console.log("zone name", name)
            var query1 = "SELECT sm.id, method_name, rate_amount, rate_min, rate_max, delivry_min, delivry_max, shipping_zone_id, factors_id, factor_name FROM `shipping_method` sm, `factors` f  where sm.shipping_zone_id = " + id + " and f.id = sm.factors_id"
            var query2 = "SELECT * FROM `country` WHERE shipping_zone_id = " + id
            connection.query(query1 + ";" + query2, function (error, results, fields) {
                var shippingMethods = results[0].map(_getShippingMethod);
                var countries = results[1].map(_getShippedCountries)
                callback({ id: id, name: name, shippingMethods: shippingMethods, countries: countries });
            });
        }
    })
}


function _getShippingMethod(result) {
    return {
        id: result.id,
        methodName: result.method_name,
        rateAmount: result.rate_amount,
        rateMin: result.rate_min,
        rateMax: result.rate_max,
        deliveryMin: result.delivry_min,
        deliveryMax: result.delivry_max,
        factorName: {
            id: result.factors_id,
            name: result.factor_name
        }
    };
}


function _getShippedCountries(result) {
    return {
        id: result.id,
        name: result.name,
        countryCode: result.country_code
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're very nearly at the right result.. the solution should be fairly simple. The [async](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async) library follows the Node.js pattern of [*error first callbacks*](https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_error_first_callbacks), so when you're returning the result of a successful operation you need to do:

```
callback(null, result).
```

or in the case of an error being encountered:

```
callback(error)
```

Otherwise async.map thinks we've encountered an error and stops. (See [async.map documentation](https://github.com/caolan/async/blob/v1.5.2/README.md#map))

In the function getShippingMethods you were calling the callback with the result as the first argument, this should be the second argument - so we don't stop the iteration.

We'll just change the getShippingMethods function like so:

```
function getShippingMethods(result, callback) {
 pool.getConnection(function (error, connection) {
    if (error) return (error)
    else {
        var id = result.id
        var name = result.zone_name
        console.log("zone name", name)
        var query1 = "SELECT sm.id, method_name, rate_amount, rate_min, rate_max, delivry_min, delivry_max, shipping_zone_id, factors_id, factor_name FROM `shipping_method` sm, `factors` f  where sm.shipping_zone_id = " + id + " and f.id = sm.factors_id"
        var query2 = "SELECT * FROM `country` WHERE shipping_zone_id = " + id
        connection.query(query1 + ";" + query2, function (error, results, fields) {
            if (error) {
                // Our query failed, so we pass error as the first argument to the callback.
                callback(error)
            } else {
                var shippingMethods = results[0].map(_getShippingMethod);
                var countries = results[1].map(_getShippedCountries)
                // This is an error first callback, so pass null here since our query was successful
                callback(null, { id: id, name: name, shippingMethods: shippingMethods, countries: countries });
            }
        });
    }
 })
}
```

And we need to change getShippingZones like so:

```
function getShippingZones() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        pool.getConnection(function (error, connection) {
            if (error) reject("error in connection")
            else {
                connection.query("select * from shipping_zone", function (error, result, fields) {
                    if (error) reject(error)
                    else {
                        // Change to an error first callback.
                        async.map(result, getShippingMethods, function (err, res) {
                            if (err) {
                                reject(err);
                            } else { 
                                resolve(res);
                            }
                        })
                    }
                })
            }
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: you made my day.

Comment: Great! It was a tricky error to diagnose. I've had the same issue myself before and it was very confusing!